# How to loop through several database in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have around 50 different databases and inside each of these database there is a table with the same name. Now, I have a written a query which extract selected fields from the table, but I need to manually select the database. How do I write a query so that I can pass database name and pull the data from that table?
Here is my code:

```
;WITH Review as (
select  external_id as sponsorid, name as sponsorname, memberid, startdate, paidamt, code
from  test.dev.sraw c left join client.dbo.sponsors s on c.customerid = s.external_id
where   year(startdate) >2009   and startdate <> '0001-01-01'   and startdate <> '1000-01-01'),

 FinalDataCollection as (select sponsorid,  sponsorname, count(*) as NbrOfClaims,  count(distinct memberid) as NbrOfMembers,  month(startdate) as mnth,  year(startdate) as yr,  sum(cast(paidamt as money)) as dollars, case when  code > '0' then 'RX' else 'med' end as category, case when  count(distinct memberid)> 0 then sum(cast(paidamt as money))/count(distinct memberid) else 0 end as costpm
 from Review
 group by sponsorid,  sponsorname,year(startdate), month(startdate),case when  code > '0' then 'RX' else 'med' end)

 select * from FinalDataCollection
```

UPDATE #1
How do I replace `''SELECT top 5 * FROM '' + @db + ''.dbo.RAW''` of the following query with the above SQL query that start with `;WITH CTE`

```
DECLARE @dbname NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @SQLString = 
'DECLARE @db NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE DB_CURSOR  CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT db.name from sys.databases db WHERE db.name  IN 
        (''A'',''B'',''C'' ) ORDER BY db.name
    OPEN DB_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM DB_CURSOR INTO @db
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC(''SELECT top 5 * FROM '' + @db + ''.dbo.RAW'')
        FETCH NEXT FROM DB_CURSOR INTO @db
    END
CLOSE DB_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE DB_CURSOR'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Thank you

Comment: read up on dynamic Sql and teh problems inhernet in using it. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure having one parameter `@DbName` thus:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetDataFromMyTable (
@DbName SYSNAME -- or NVARCHAR(128)
)
AS
BEGIN
IF DB_ID(@DbName) IS NOT NULL AND @DbName IN (N'MyDB1', N'MyDB2', N'MyDB3', ...)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @SqlStatement = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DbName) + N'; SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2 FROM dbo.MyTable';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement;
END
ELSE
    RAISERROR('Wrong database.', 16, 1);
END
```

END;

Notes:

`DB_ID(@DbName) IS NOT NULL` -- It checks if `@DbName` exists

`@DbName IN (N'MyDB1', N'MyDB2', ..., N'MyDBn')` -- It checks if `@DbName` is on the white list with allowed database (from this point of view, first check is, somehow, redundant).

Why I've used `QUOTENAME(@DbName)` ? See section [Wrapping Parameters with QUOTENAME() and REPLACE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx): if the content of `@variable` is a securable (ex. a database / table) then the recommended wrapper is `QUOTENAME(@variable)`.

You could replace `@DbName IN (N'MyDB1', N'MyDB2', ..., N'MyDBn')` with `exists` thus:

```
EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT N'MyDB1' UNION ALL 
        SELECT N'MyDB2' UNION ALL 
        ...
        SELECT N'MyDBn'
    ) dbs(DbName)
    WHERE dbs.DbName = @DbName
)
```

**Update #1:**

You have to replace

`SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2 FROM dbo.MyTable`

with

```
WITH Review as (
select  external_id as sponsorid, name as sponsorname, memberid, startdate, paidamt, code
from  test.dev.sraw c left join client.dbo.sponsors s on c.customerid = s.external_id
where   year(startdate) >2009   and startdate <> ''0001-01-01''   and startdate <> ''1000-01-01''),

 FinalDataCollection as (select sponsorid,  sponsorname, count(*) as NbrOfClaims,  count(distinct memberid) as NbrOfMembers,  month(startdate) as mnth,  year(startdate) as yr,  sum(cast(paidamt as money)) as dollars, case when  code > ''0'' then ''RX'' else ''med'' end as category, case when  count(distinct memberid)> 0 then sum(cast(paidamt as money))/count(distinct memberid) else 0 end as costpm
 from Review
 group by sponsorid,  sponsorname,year(startdate), month(startdate),case when  code > ''0'' then ''RX'' else ''med'' end)

 select * from FinalDataCollection
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan, my select statement involves CTE. How do I handle that? Thank you

Comment: You have to change `SET ... + N'; SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2 FROM dbo.MyTable';` with your query `SET ... + N'; WITH CTE1(...) SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2 FROM dbo.CTE1';`

Comment: Hi Bogdan, for some reason I couldn't get it work. I have modified my original question with the code that I am trying to make dynamic. Could you please review it and suggest me how I can make it workable. Thank you

Comment: @poshan: See Update #1.

Comment: +1: Nice Answer.  For the `EXISTS` subclause, you could simplify this by creating a table to hold the names of the 50 databases, which would probably have other uses and be easier to mantian as well.

Comment: Thank you Bogdan. This is working now. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I just create a common database for this kind of thing.  Works for me.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, I have one more question. In your update #1 SQL, how would you dump the result into a temp table. I tried select * into #temptbl from FInalDatacollection then got message 'two rows affected' but when I tried select * from #temptbl, it said invalid object name. Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Try `CREATE TABLE #Tab (...); INSERT INTO #Tab EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement;`

Comment: Hi Bogdan, I have added one update on my initial question.  When I execute the query in the UPDATE #1, it gets executed. However, when I tried to replace the same select statement with the initial SQL query ( query above my update #1) I can't get it worked. I am unable to write the syntax properly. Would you mind suggesting some tips to me? Thank you